# Codeigniter database reconnect not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller that does uploading to the host server and another controller that does uploading to youtube. After the former controller does its job, it redirects to the latter. After a particularly long uploading process which involves youtube, I was getting "MySQL server has gone away" errors

I used this code to reconnect to database in Codeigniter to solve that problem.

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

Instead I got an error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to select the specified database: test_database
....
```

I tried adding this code before and after the "reconnect" code but it did not help('test' below is the name of the active group in the database config I am using.)

```
$this->load->database('test');
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Calling **reconnect()** with auto-reconnect disabled in MySQL will throw an error, and depending on your error status in your config file and PHP install will display and log the error.

The best way to do it is just close the connection and reconnect manually with:

```
$this->db->close();
$this->db->initialize();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think $this->db->initialize() function exists. I assume you mean $this->db->load().

Comment: `$this->db->initialize()` method exists `system/database/DB_driver.php` for CI 2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

You might actually want to extend the database class then implement the your own reconnection process. You can implement something like this:

```
...
if(!mysql_ping($this -> conn_id)) {
    $this -> _close();
    $this -> db_connect();
}
...
```

To know how to extend the database class see this link:

[Extending Database Drivers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers)